# How to solve Dex error when building bundle for Ionic 5?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I tried to build bundle from my application. This is an Ionic 5 capacitor mobile app and I was able to test it on mobile with android studio. And now that I'm trying to configure google play internal test and building bundle to create a release. I'm getting this error when building:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type fr.studnchill.stoudy.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: D:\\Web\\studnchill\\android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\project_dex_archive\\release\\out\\fr\\studnchill\\stoudy\\BuildConfig.dex, D:\\Web\\studnchill\\android\\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\\build\\.transforms\\f61fa6804b2b8426f5a20ba8cb875575\\transformed\\classes\\classes.dex","sources":[{"file":"D:\\Web\\studnchill\\android\\app\\build\\intermediates\\project_dex_archive\\release\\out\\fr\\studnchill\\stoudy\\BuildConfig.dex"}],"tool":"D8"}
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Type fr.studnchill.stoudy.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: D:\Web\studnchill\android\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\fr\studnchill\stoudy\BuildConfig.dex, D:\Web\studnchill\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\build\.transforms\f61fa6804b2b8426f5a20ba8cb875575\transformed\classes\classes.dex
Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:128)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:115)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:111)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.merge(DexMergingTask.kt:805)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction.run(DexMergingTask.kt:760)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.ProfileAwareWorkAction.execute(ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt:74)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:206)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:214)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: D:\Web\studnchill\android\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\fr\studnchill\stoudy\BuildConfig.dex
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_2.2.66.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.a0.a(SourceFile:89)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:113)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type fr.studnchill.stoudy.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: D:\Web\studnchill\android\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\fr\studnchill\stoudy\BuildConfig.dex, D:\Web\studnchill\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\build\.transforms\f61fa6804b2b8426f5a20ba8cb875575\transformed\classes\classes.dex
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.V0.a(SourceFile:22)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.V0.a(SourceFile:25)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.b(SourceFile:6)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.a(SourceFile:24)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.a(SourceFile:10)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2048)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.T0.a(SourceFile:6)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.i1$c.e(SourceFile:3)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.a.a(SourceFile:336)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.a.a(SourceFile:265)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(D8.java:22)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(D8.java:6)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(D8.java:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.a0.a(SourceFile:47)
    ... 38 more


Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: D:\Web\studnchill\android\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\fr\studnchill\stoudy\BuildConfig.dex

Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Type fr.studnchill.stoudy.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: D:\Web\studnchill\android\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\fr\studnchill\stoudy\BuildConfig.dex, D:\Web\studnchill\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\build\.transforms\f61fa6804b2b8426f5a20ba8cb875575\transformed\classes\classes.dex

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
   > There was a failure while executing work items
      > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
         > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
           Type fr.studnchill.stoudy.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: D:\Web\studnchill\android\app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\fr\studnchill\stoudy\BuildConfig.dex, D:\Web\studnchill\android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\build\.transforms\f61fa6804b2b8426f5a20ba8cb875575\transformed\classes\classes.dex
           Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I already tried a lot of things I saw on internet but really don't understand how to fix this maybe if someone can help me ?

Comment: dex problems could be occur in case u got corrupted android studio sdk packages... either try to reinstall the packages for ur target sdk version or at the end u may neeed to reinstall android studio with new sdks...

Comment: I tried to change SDK version but nothing change but can it be link to ion-native or capacitor plugin because before my app did build ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got this to works by just rebuild all project from scratch and paste all files in it. Maybe some bad dependencies in the project ?